# Custom HtmlHelper for a dropdownlist shows all the values as plain text instead of building a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html-helper

I have tried to build a custom DropDownList using this method here:

http://blog.platformular.com/2011/12/16/country-drop-down-html-helper-for-asp-net-mvc/

Basically, the helper loads an Html File, then populates the dropdownlist based on the information found in the file.

But rather than building the dropdownlist, my app shows all the data in the view this way:

```
Country: <select name="countryCode" id="countryCode"><option value="">Please select</option><option value="AF"
>Afghanistan</option><option value="AL" >Albania</option><option value="DZ" >Algeria</option><option value="AS" >American Samoa</option><option value="AD" >Andorra</option><option value="AO"
>Angola</option><option value="AI" >Anguilla</option><option value="AQ" >Antarctica</option><option value="AG" >Antigua And Barbuda</option><option value="AR" >Argentina</option><option value="AM" >Armenia</option><option value="AW" >Aruba</option><option value="AU" >Australia</option><option value="AT"
>Austria</option><option value="AZ" >Azerbaijan</option><option value="BS" >Bahamas</option><option value="BH"
>Bahrain</option><option value="BD" >Bangladesh</option><option value="BB" >Barbados</option><option value="BY"
>Belarus</option><option value="BE" >Belgium</option><option value="BZ" >Belize</option><option value="BJ" >Benin</option><option value="BM" >Bermuda</option><option value="BT" >Bhutan</option><option value="BO" >Bolivia</option><option value="BA" >Bosnia And Herzegovina</option><option value="BW" >Botswana</option><option value="BV" >Bouvet Island</option><option value="BR"
>Brazil</option><option value="IO" >British Indian Ocean Territory</option><option value="BN" >Brunei Darussalam</option><option value="BG" >Bulgaria</option><option value="BF" >Burkina Faso</option><option value="BI"
>Burundi</option><option value="KH" >Cambodia</option><option value="CM" >Cameroon</option><option value="CA"
>Canada</option><option value="CV" >Cape Verde</option><option value="KY" >Cayman Islands</option><option value="CF" >Central African Republic</option><option value="TD" >Chad</option><option value="CL"
>Chile</option><option value="CN" >China</option><option value="CX" >Christmas Island</option><option value="CC" >Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option><option value="CO" >Colombia</option><option value="KM" >Comoros</option><option value="CG" >Congo</option><option value="CK" >Cook Islands</option><option value="CR" >Costa Rica</option><option value="CI" >Cote D'Ivoire</option><option value="HR" >Croatia (Local Name: Hrvatska)</option><option value="CU"
>Cuba</option><option value="CY" >Cyprus</option><option value="CZ" >Czech Republic</option><option value="DK" >Denmark</option><option value="DJ" >Djibouti</option><option value="DM"
>Dominica</option><option value="DO" >Dominican Republic</option><option value="EC" >Ecuador</option><option value="EG" >Egypt</option><option value="SV" >El Salvador</option><option value="GQ" >Equatorial Guinea</option><option value="ER" >Eritrea</option><option value="EE"
>Estonia</option><option value="ET" >Ethiopia</option><option value="FK" >Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option><option value="FO"
>Faroe Islands</option><option value="FJ" >Fiji</option><option value="FI" >Finland</option><option value="FR" >France</option><option value="FX" >France, Metropolitan</option><option value="GF" >French Guiana</option><option value="PF" >French Polynesia</option><option value="TF" >French Southern Territories</option><option value="GA"
>Gabon</option><option value="GM" >Gambia</option><option value="GE" >Georgia</option><option value="DE" >Germany</option><option value="GH" >Ghana</option><option value="GI"
>Gibraltar</option><option value="GR" >Greece</option><option value="GL" >Greenland</option><option value="GD"
>Grenada</option><option value="GP" >Guadeloupe</option><option value="GU" >Guam</option><option value="GT" >Guatemala</option><option value="GN" >Guinea</option><option value="GW"
>Guinea-Bissau</option><option value="GY" >Guyana</option><option value="HT" >Haiti</option><option value="HM" >Heard Island & Mcdonald Islands</option><option value="HN" >Honduras</option><option value="HK" >Hong Kong</option><option value="HU"
>Hungary</option><option value="IS" >Iceland</option><option value="IN" >India</option><option value="ID"
>Indonesia</option><option value="IR" >Iran, Islamic Republic Of</option><option value="IQ" >Iraq</option><option value="IE"
>Ireland</option><option value="IL" >Israel</option><option value="IT" >Italy</option><option value="JM" >Jamaica</option><option value="JP" >Japan</option><option value="JO" >Jordan</option><option value="KZ" >Kazakhstan</option><option value="KE" >Kenya</option><option value="KI" >Kiribati</option><option value="KP" >Korea, Democratic People'S Republic Of</option><option value="KR" >Korea, Republic Of</option><option value="KW" >Kuwait</option><option value="KG"
>Kyrgyzstan</option><option value="LA" >Lao People'S Democratic Republic</option><option value="LV" >Latvia</option><option value="LB"
>Lebanon</option><option value="LS" >Lesotho</option><option value="LR" >Liberia</option><option value="LY" >Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option><option value="LI" >Liechtenstein</option><option value="LT" >Lithuania</option><option value="LU"
>Luxembourg</option><option value="MO" >Macau</option><option value="MK" >Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic Of</option><option value="MG" >Madagascar</option><option value="MW"
>Malawi</option><option value="MY" >Malaysia</option><option value="MV" >Maldives</option><option value="ML" >Mali</option><option value="MT" >Malta</option><option value="MH" >Marshall Islands</option><option value="MQ" >Martinique</option><option value="MR" >Mauritania</option><option value="MU"
>Mauritius</option><option value="YT" >Mayotte</option><option value="MX" >Mexico</option><option value="FM" >Micronesia, Federated States Of</option><option value="MD" >Moldova, Republic Of</option><option value="MC" >Monaco</option><option value="MN"
>Mongolia</option><option value="MS" >Montserrat</option><option value="MA" >Morocco</option><option value="MZ"
>Mozambique</option><option value="MM" >Myanmar</option><option value="NA" >Namibia</option><option value="NR" >Nauru</option><option value="NP" >Nepal</option><option value="NL"
>Netherlands</option><option value="AN" >Netherlands Antilles</option><option value="NC" >New Caledonia</option><option value="NZ" >New Zealand</option><option value="NI"
>Nicaragua</option><option value="NE" >Niger</option><option value="NG" >Nigeria</option><option value="NU" >Niue</option><option value="NF" >Norfolk Island</option><option value="MP" >Northern Mariana Islands</option><option value="NO" >Norway</option><option value="OM" >Oman</option><option value="PK" >Pakistan</option><option value="PW" >Palau</option><option value="PA" >Panama</option><option value="PG" >Papua New Guinea</option><option value="PY"
>Paraguay</option><option value="PE" >Peru</option><option value="PH" >Philippines</option><option value="PN" >Pitcairn</option><option value="PL" >Poland</option><option value="PT"
>Portugal</option><option value="PR" >Puerto Rico</option><option value="QA" >Qatar</option><option value="RE" >Reunion</option><option value="RO" >Romania</option><option value="RU" >Russian Federation</option><option value="RW" >Rwanda</option><option value="SH" >Saint Helena</option><option value="KN" >Saint Kitts And Nevis</option><option value="LC" >Saint Lucia</option><option value="PM" >Saint Pierre And Miquelon</option><option value="VC"
>Saint Vincent And The Grenadines</option><option value="WS" >Samoa</option><option value="SM" >San Marino</option><option value="ST" >Sao Tome And Principe</option><option value="SA" >Saudi Arabia</option><option value="SN" >Senegal</option><option value="SC"
>Seychelles</option><option value="SL" >Sierra Leone</option><option value="SG" >Singapore</option><option value="SK" >Slovakia (Slovak Republic)</option><option value="SI" >Slovenia</option><option value="SB" >Solomon Islands</option><option value="SO"
>Somalia</option><option value="ZA" >South Africa</option><option value="ES" >Spain</option><option value="LK" >Sri Lanka</option><option value="SD" >Sudan</option><option value="SR"
>Suriname</option><option value="SJ" >Svalbard And Jan Mayen Islands</option><option value="SZ" >Swaziland</option><option value="SE" >Sweden</option><option value="CH"
>Switzerland</option><option value="SY" >Syrian Arab Republic</option><option value="TW" >Taiwan</option><option value="TJ"
>Tajikistan</option><option value="TZ" >Tanzania, United Republic Of</option><option value="TH" >Thailand</option><option value="TG"
>Togo</option><option value="TK" >Tokelau</option><option value="TO" >Tonga</option><option value="TT" >Trinidad And Tobago</option><option value="TN" >Tunisia</option><option value="TR" >Turkey</option><option value="TM" >Turkmenistan</option><option value="TC" >Turks And Caicos Islands</option><option value="TV" >Tuvalu</option><option value="UG"
>Uganda</option><option value="UA" >Ukraine</option><option value="AE" >United Arab Emirates</option><option value="GB" >United Kingdom</option><option value="US" >United States</option><option value="UM" >United States Minor Outlying Islands</option><option value="UY" >Uruguay</option><option value="UZ"
>Uzbekistan</option><option value="VU" >Vanuatu</option><option value="VA" >Vatican City State (Holy See)</option><option value="VE"
>Venezuela</option><option value="VN" >Viet Nam</option><option value="VG" >Virgin Islands (British)</option><option value="VI"
>Virgin Islands (U.S.)</option><option value="WF" >Wallis And Futuna Islands</option><option value="EH" >Western Sahara</option><option value="YE" >Yemen</option><option value="YU"
>Yugoslavia</option><option value="ZR" >Zaire</option><option value="ZM" >Zambia</option><option value="ZW"
>Zimbabwe</option></select>
```

Here's my htmlHelper method as I have coded right now:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string CountryDropDown(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, string name, string optionLabel, object selectedValue)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/countries.xml"));

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        b.Append(string.Format("<select name=\"{0}\" id=\"{0}\">", name));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(optionLabel))
        {
            b.Append(string.Format("<option value=\"\">{0}</option>", optionLabel));
        }

        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//country"))
        {
           string selected = string.Empty;
           if (node.Attributes["code"].Value == selectedValue as string)
           {
               selected = "selected=\"selected\"";
           }
           b.Append(string.Format("<option value=\"{0}\" {2}>{1}</option>", node.Attributes["code"].Value, node.InnerText, selected));
        }
        b.Append("</select>");

        return b.ToString();
    }
}
```

And I have added those namespaces to my web.config:

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    <add namespace="MyApp.HtmlHelpers"/>
</namespaces>
```

Only the `<add namespace="MyApp.HtmlHelpers"/>`line was added though because I already had the rest.

Can anybody help me? I've never done a custom html helper before and this puzzles me.

**EDIT**

Here's how I render my view for this htmlHelper:

```
@using MyApp.HtmlHelpers

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Object Index";
}

<h2>Object Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p>
            (...)
            Country: @Html.CountryDropDown("countryCode","---Select a country---", ViewData["countryCode"])
            (...)
        </p>
    }
</p>
```

Comment: What's that info you posted? Are you saying no dropdown was built using your custom html helper? And that all was written are plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah it's because you are returning it as a plain text, you should return it as an `MvcHtmlString`

```
public static MvcHtmlStringCountryDropDown(
    this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, 
    string name, 
    string optionLabel, 
    object selectedValue)
{
    // your code goes here
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(b.ToString());
}
```